# Dynamic floating decimal point in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mathjs

I am creating a general ledger application in javascript and want to dynamically shift a number to two decimal places as an input that number.
It should happen when someone starts typing a number into a HTML input text field; I want it to work like an onKeyUp or onKeyPress event.

Examples:

1. I type "1" and the output will be "0.01"
2. I type "12" and the output will be "0.12"
3. I type "123" and the output will be "1.23"
4. I type "1234" and the output will be "12.34"

I have looked through jquery, mathjs, and have yet to find something.

Can anybody please give me some guidance?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want it to be done dynamically in an HTML text box when someone types a number?

Comment: This is a basic math problem, nothing to do with JavaSciprt, IMO.

Comment: Well... What's the mathematical relationship between `1` and `0.01` ? Find this out and you're done.

Comment: Is your question how to divide by 100?

Comment: @AakashVerma Yes, to be done dynamically in an HTML text box when someone types a number :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var value = '';
  $('input').on('keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.which != 8 && isNaN(String.fromCharCode(e.which))) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return;
    }
    if ($(this).val() == 0.00) value = '';
    if (e.keyCode == 8) {
      value = value.slice(0, -1)
    } else {
      value += e.key
    };
    var sss = (value / 100).toFixed(2);
    if (sss == "0.00")
      $(this).val('');
    else
      $(this).val(sss);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type=number>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and great code. Thank you very much!! :D

Answer (score 0):

> Can anybody please give me some guidance?

Just divide the input by **100**

```
var input = "1";
var output = input/100; //0.01
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! I would like something more along the lines of a onKeyUp or onKeyPress event.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = document.getElementById('inp');
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click',function(){
document.getElementById('opt').innerHTML = "output: " + (a.value/100)
})
```

```html
<input id='inp' type="number" />
<button id='btn'>click</button>
<div id='opt'>output:  </div>
```

Comment: this is almost exactly what I need! However, I would like it to work when I key something in on the same text box. Is that possible?